# JAVA - Можно ли создать exe файл?

Tags: java, exe

Можно ли создать exe файл в JAVA? И можно ли будет его запрограммировать?

Comment: Разумеется можно: создаете файл с именем foo.exe, к примеру, пишете в него данные из вашей программы на JAVA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Средствами JDK нельзя. Но [есть компиляторы](https://www.excelsiorjet.com), которые умеют это делать. Только они все платные.

Answer (score 1):

А [вот](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) бесплатная программа для преобразования `jar` в `exe`.

Comment: Она не преобразовывает jar в exe. Это просто упаковщик.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev на выходе получается exe файл. проверял. ну перепакует и что? за то бесплатное, суть та же.

Comment: Не та же. launch4j по сути создаст вам самораспаковывающийся архив,  содержащий в себе портабельную JRE и ваш jar-файл. При запуске всё это добро распаковывается во временный каталог и запускается. Минусы очевидны - большой размер, низкая в сравнении с обычным бинарником скорость работы, нулевая защита от декомпиляции. Упаковщики хороши только для облегчения распространения мелких утилит.